# How do I find abandoned projects in Sourceforge/GitHub?

Tags: github, computer-science, sourceforge

I'd like to find some abandoned projects which I could potentially look/study the code of and update them if I can. How do I go about finding such?

Comment: Why abandoned? On GitHub you can clone almost any public project and, if you know how to improve it, do a merge request.

Comment: How are you defining "abandoned"?  How can you, as a human, know if something is abandoned?  When you define that, then you can figure out how to get the computer to tell you.

Comment: @AndyLester Projects on Sourceforge are Listed as "abandoned" by owners. There is just no way to search for all abandoned projects

Comment: Aha, I didn't realize that it was an actual status of the project.

Answer (score 1):

How about this: Google for `site:sourceforge.net abandoned`.  It turns up projects like the game "Abandoned Mansion", but it also finds mostly projects that are abandoned.